# Why does Kramer's theorem only apply to systems with an odd number of fermions?

Tags: angular-momentum, fermions, time-reversal-symmetry

[Kramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers_theorem) states that: In a time reversal symmetric system, where $T^2=-1$, all energy levels are (at least) doubly degenerate.

I claim to have proven this in a simple way.
We first establish that $|\Psi\rangle$ and $T|\Psi\rangle$ are different states. Let's assume the opposite, that the states are equivalent, then, $$T|\Psi\rangle=e^{i\phi}|\Psi\rangle.$$
Which implies that, $$T^2|\Psi\rangle=Te^{i\phi}|\Psi\rangle=e^{-i\phi}T|\Psi\rangle=e^{-i\phi+i\phi}|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi\rangle.$$
From which it follows that $T^2=1$, contrary to our requirement. Thus $|\Psi\rangle$ and $T|\Psi\rangle$ are unique states. Then trivially, $H|\Psi\rangle=E|\Psi\rangle$ and $$HT|\Psi\rangle=TH|\Psi\rangle=ET|\Psi\rangle.$$ So that both $|\Psi\rangle$ and $T|\Psi\rangle$ have the same energy! The system is doubly degenerate.
But nowehere was it assumed that the system must have an odd number of fermions. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assuming $T^2=-1$. You can have $T^2=1$ too, in which case it is perfectly fine to have $\psi$ and $T\psi$ be the same state, as you showed in your question. But it turns out the states with $T^2=-1$ are just the states with half-integer angular momentum, as I'll show.

$T$ anticommutes with angular momentum (since it should flip the sign). If I consider a particle at rest, and use a basis in terms of eigenstates of z-angular momentum $\psi_\sigma$, we have
$$T\psi_\sigma = \zeta_\sigma \psi_{-\sigma}$$
where $\zeta_\sigma$ is some phase factor that might depend on $\sigma$. *Notice we see right away that we can't have $T\psi\propto\psi$ for a particle with half integer spin, since there is no $\sigma=0$ state.* That is more or less what you wanted to see I think but let's go a little further.

If we apply the raising and lowering operator $J_\pm=J_x\pm iJ_y$
$$J_\pm T \psi_\sigma=\zeta_\sigma J_\pm \psi_{-\sigma}\propto \zeta_\sigma \psi_{-\sigma\pm 1}$$
where there's also that normalization factor with a square root you can look up. But we also have,
$$J_{\pm}T\psi_\sigma = -TJ_\mp \psi_\sigma \propto -\zeta_{\sigma\mp 1}\psi_{-\sigma\pm 1} $$
The normalization factor is the same in both cases so
$$\zeta_{\sigma}=-\zeta_{\sigma\mp 1}$$
So the sign flips each time you raise or lower z-angular momentum, so we can write (up to an overall phase we can absorb into our definition of $\psi$)
$$\zeta_\sigma = (-1)^{j-\sigma}$$
where $j$ is the total angular momenta. So we have
$$T^2\psi_\sigma=(-1)^{j+\sigma}(-1)^{j-\sigma}\psi_\sigma=(-1)^{2j}\psi_\sigma$$
So $T^2=\pm 1$ depending on whether $j$ is an integer or half integer.

Comment: And $j$ is total angular momentum, so $j=l+\sigma$. Where $l$ is always integer, and $\sigma$ is half integer while we have an odd number of fermions and even while we have an even number of fermions. Is that it?


Furthermore I do not under stand how you were able to write $\zeta_\sigma=(-1)^{j-\sigma}$.

Thank you so much, but I would love to ge these two points clarified.

Comment: @Mongelo, Yes $j$ is total angular momentum. The orbital part of the angular momentum is always integer, so your total $j$ will be half integer if and only if you have an odd number of fermions. Do you see why $\zeta_\sigma=(-1)^{j-\sigma}\zeta$ where $\zeta$ is some overall phase? The (-1) part is just there so the sign alternates ever other $\sigma$ as we found in the previous line. Well you can get rid of any overall $\zeta$ if you redefine your states as $\psi'=\zeta^{1/2}\psi$. I'm running out of space, but you can see yourself that this works if you remember $T$ complex conjugates.

Comment: And actually, if you don't like the idea of redefining your states, it's no big deal since $$T^2 \psi_\sigma = T (-1)^{j-\sigma}\zeta\psi_{-\sigma} = (-1)^{j-\sigma}\zeta^*T\psi_{-\sigma}=(-1)^{2j}\zeta^*\zeta  \psi_\sigma =(-1)^{2j}  \psi_\sigma $$

Comment: I think my confusion arrises from the raising operator. Does $J_+$ really increase $\sigma$? Shouldn't it just increase $m_j$?

Comment: Oh, $\sigma$ is $m_j$. Sorry should've been more clear about my notation.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but I'm still unsure how $(-1)^j$ enters into $\zeta_\sigma$. To me it seems like $\zeta_\sigma=-\zeta_{\sigma\mp1}$ only implies that $\zeta_{\sigma}=(-1)^{-\sigma}$. Where does the $j$ come from?

Comment: No problem, good question. You can consider the $(-1)^j$ to be an overall phase factor $\zeta$ if you want. But notice if $\sigma$ and $j$ are half integer, then $(-1)^{-\sigma}$ by itself is imaginary and we need to complex conjugate it (unlike if we kept $(-1)^j$ around). Then if you follow the $T^2$ argument you'll still get an overall minus.

Comment: I would like to understand why I can think of $\zeta$ as $(-1)^j$, because you didn't prove that, right? Feel free to give up on me here. I have learned a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: $\zeta$ is just the name we're giving all overall phase factors that don't depend on $\sigma$. It doesn't matter exactly what phase $\zeta$ is, because it ends up canceling as I showed in a comment above, and it also depends on an arbitrary convention of how we pick the phase of $\psi_\sigma$. Since $\zeta$ is arbitrary we can always include an extra $(-1)^j$ in it if we want (since that doesn't depend on sigma). But if we do keep an extra $(-1)^j$ floating around, then $(-1)^{j-\sigma}$ is real no matter if we are dealing with bosons or fermions.